# Possible Playable Chords on a Guitar

Tags: combinatorics, music-theory

### Fingerstyle Guitar Chord Diversity Check

Considering a $20$-fret $6$-string acoustic guitar and supposing that the fretting range (inclusive of the fingered notes) for an average hand is $4$ frets in the first $8$ frets, $5$ frets in the $9-14$ fret region and $6$ frets on the remaining of the fretboard, how many combinations of at least $3$ different notes can be strummed if we ignore barring and use at most $4$ fingers to fret?

[image]

We would have the worst fretting range if our fingered frets involve any of the $3$ prescribed regions *down the fretboard* (i.e. $8$ fret region, $9−14$ fret region and the remaining of the fretboard). Suppose you decide to fret $12$ on the first string, then, the lowest other fret you can finger is $9$ since fretting $8$ would require a fret range of $5$ while playing $8$ reduces your fret range to $4$ since we consider the worst fret range on overlapping fret regions.

In our case, a chord is defined as a collection of $3$ to $6$ distinct notes strummed together. Each chord is unique. For example, fretting $3$ on sixth string, $2$ on the fifth string, $3$ on the first string and strumming all 6 strings is the same as fretting $3$ on sixth string, $2$ on the fifth string, $3$ on the second string and $3$ on the first string and strumming all 6 strings as both would produce a $\text{G}$ chord.

Comment: +1 you have tried (better than most) to define the problem well.  The transitions need further definition.  If I finger $12$, can I do $6$?  How about $19$?

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for pointing this out. We would have the worst fretting range if our fingered frets involve any of the 3 prescribed ranges (i.e. $8$ fret range, $9-14$ fret range and the remaining of the fretboard). Suppose you decide to fret $12$ on the first string and to fret $8$ on the second string, then you are bound to select the remaining two notes within the $8-12$ $5$-fret region.

Comment: I've changed the fret ranges a bit for practical reasons...

Comment: Are we supposed to take into account that you can often get the same note from more than one string (e.g. the highest string free = E = fifth fret on the second highest string)? Or can we, for the purposes of this exercise, assume that the strings are so badly out of tune that there is zero overlap with the notes available from distinct strings :-)

Comment: But the question is still also a bit undefined in the sense that how do you decide which combinations of frets are ok, when they fall into different ranges? For example, if fret 14 is included, then are we to interpret it in the way that we cannot simultaneously use fret 20, because that is six frets away, and fret 14 is in the "five range". OTOH fret 20 is in the "six range", so that would suggest that the pair $(14,20)$ is ok. I think that you may have to describe the pairs of frets $(m,n)$ within reach by some other means.

Comment: But a fun question nevertheless! Once the ambiguities are cleared up, I think I would approach it simply by writing a computer program enumerating the possibilities. It could get nasty, I haven't really thought about it, but I don't think there is a simple formula for this

Comment: What is a "combination of at least 3 possible notes"? Does that mean that 3 to 6 strings are strummed? And does your definition of "chord" implicitly require concordance?

Comment: @PeterTaylor $3$ different notes played at the same time implies that they are strummed on at least $3$ strings. They may be any strings considering that one has an ability to mute any of the middle strings by will.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for pointing out the question in your first comment... The 3 notes should be distinct such that each chord is **UNIQUE**. For example, fretting $3$ on sixth string, $2$ on the fifth string, $3$ on the first string is the same as fretting $3$ on sixth string, $2$ on the fifth string, $3$ on the second string and $3$ on the first string as both would produce a $\text{G}$ chord. Whereas for your second comment, I answered the question in my first comment.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen We will consider the worst possible fretting range for overlapping regions. If any of the notes you fret are on the 1-8 fret region then your fretting range is always 4. Consider the case when you first finger 12th fret on the sixth string. Then on the lowest you can fret 9th fret not 8th because 9th fret, which is at distance 4 (inclusive) of fret 12, allows you to have a 5 fret range while fretting 8, at a distance of 5 (inclusive) from 12th fret, would bound you to a 4 fret range and hence not possible to fret.

Comment: Ok. It just dawned on me that you are, of course, counting "down the fretboard".

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by unique.  The example you give would be the same if I only strum strings 1,5,6 but would not be if I strum strings 1,2,5,6 it seems.  If I strum them all it also seems they are different.  Do the strings I strum have to be contiguous?

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for pointing this out... I've edited the last para for clarity. Please point out any ambiguity if it arises.

Comment: It seems like in your example, one of the notes is different-the one produced by the second string.  I can understand the chords would be the same if I didn't play the second string, but if I do, it seems they are different.  When you say they are both G chords we need to understand that rule.

Comment: The notes that correspond to $3-2-0-0-0-3$ are $\text{G-B-D-G-B-G}$ while the notes that correspond to $3-2-0-0-3-3$ are $\text{G-B-D-G-D-G}$. Now since both the arrangements contain $\text{G}$, $\text{B}$ and $\text{D}$ as distinct notes, we say that they both are equivalent chords or the $\text{G}$ chord.

Comment: There's [a general and systematic way](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/dm-reading-assignments/Application%20of%20Burnside%20Lemma%20to%20Music%20Theory.pdf) to compute the number of chords that can be formed up to transpositions, inversions, etc... using Burnside's theorem. I'm sure it can be adapted to this problem.

Comment: "Fingerstyle Guitar Chord Diversity Check" would be a pretty good name for an indie band.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following is not really specific to guitar music, but a general approach that could be specialized to guitar music with further restrictions.

[Dmitri Tymoczko](http://dmitri.tymoczko.com/) has tried to develop a kind of geometrical theory of chord spaces. I found it interesting insofar as it managed to get some structure, I didn't find it at all useful when it comes to making music though. But I'm sure this is something you want to look into. His is not the only approach though.

Anyway, while trying to understand his papers, I started to do my own computations to determine how many different chords of 3, 4, 5,... notes there exist. The key here is [Burnside's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma) from group theory. Let me illustrate for the case of 3 note chords.

First, we have to establish the space we are working on. We'll start from the conventional Western 12 tones in equal temperament, but if you want to make quarter tone or microtonal music or use different temperaments, you can easily adapt my story. Each tone will get a number from 0 to 11, we'll work modulo 12 since the twelfth tone is just the 0th an octave higher. So that's a first symmetry that is already implicit in the definition of our space. In modern harmony, this is called a [pitch class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_class). Now, since we consider 3-tone chords, we are going to present them as follows

$$\text{CMaj}=\{\text{C,E,G}\}=\{0,4,7\} \\
\text{Cmin}=\{\text{C,Eb,G}\}=\{0,3,7\} \\
\text{FMaj 2nd inversion}=\{\text{C,F,A}\}=\{0,5,9\} \\$$

Then we are going to introduce additional symmetries. We consider all chords that can be transposed into each other to be the same chord. For instance

$$\text{FMaj}=\{\text{F,A,C}\}=\{5,9,0\}\overset{T}{=}\{5-5,9-5,0-5\}=\{0,4,7\}=\text{CMaj} \; .$$

Next, we are also going to identify inversions, which mathematically amounts to permutations of the elements

$$\text{FMaj 2nd inversion}=\{\text{C,F,A}\}=\{0,5,9\}\overset{P}{=}\{5,9,0\}\overset{T}{=}\{0,4,7\}=\text{CMaj} \; .$$

One could go further and add additional symmetries, for instance

$$\text{Cmin}=\{\text{C,Eb,G}\}=\{0,3,7\}\overset{I}{=}\{7-0,7-3,7-7\}\overset{P}{=}\{0,4,7\}=\text{CMaj} \; .$$

But since this turns major chords into minor chords and visa versa and these are usually considered distinct in conventional harmony, we're not going that way. One might argue that even inversions of chords should be considered separately because of their different functions, but for the sake of the present argument, I'm gonna stick to two symmetries $P$ and $T$.

Now, let's see how we can apply Burnside's lemma. Our space of 3-tone chords is $X$ and is acted upon by a group $G$ generated by transpositions $T$ on one hand and permutations $P$ on the other. Burnside's lemma tells us that

$$|X/G|=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|X^g|$$

or in human words: the number of 3-tone chords up to transpositions and permutations is found by adding for each symmetry element the number of chords fixed by that certain symmetry and dividing by the total number of symmetries acting upon the space. $X/G$ is called in jargon the set of **orbits**. Whereas $X^g$ is the set of **fixed elements** under the action of $g$.

Applying this to our 3-tone chords set, we really only have to look at what happens under permutations since transpositions can never fix elements. So, we have 6 possible permutations:

$$ \{\text{Id},(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)\} \; .$$

The identity fixes all $12^3$ elements of our space. The three following permutations fix elements of the form $\{a,a,b\},\{a,b,a\}$ and $\{b,a,a\}$ resp. thus accounting each for $12^2$ fixed elements. The last two are more tricky. Obviously elements of the form $\{a,a,a\}$ are fixed. But also elements of the form $\{a,a+4,a+8\}$ and $\{a,a+8,a+16\}$ are. This accounts for a total of $6 \times 12$ elements. Applying Burnside's lemma, the amount of distinct 3-tone chords is

$$\frac{12^3+3\times 12^2+6\times 12}{12\times 6}=31 \; .$$

Among these 31 chords are however a bunch of chords containing repeated tones, 12 to be precise. If we leave those 12 out, we are left with 19 chords. Leaving out 9 more that contain a minor second interval leaves us with the following 10 chords

$$\{\text{C,E,G#}\},\{\text{C,E,G}\},\{\text{C,Eb,G}\},\{\text{C,D,F#}\},\{\text{C,E,Gb}\},\{\text{C,D,G}\},\{\text{C,D,E}\},\{\text{C,Eb,F}\},\{\text{C,Eb,Gb}\},\{\text{C,D,F}\}$$

The first three chords are resp. the augmented triad, the major triad and the minor triad. The second to last triad is the diminished triad. Those are very common in classical harmony. Chords like $\{\text{C,D,G}\}$ are used in [quartal and quintal harmony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartal_and_quintal_harmony). It is however also understood as a suspended fourth in classical and jazz harmony.

Note that it is possible in my analysis to exclude repeated notes from the onset. The sequence of integers for the number of chords consisting of several distinct notes is listed [on OEIS with number A035495](http://oeis.org/A035495) and continues as follows:

$$1, 1, 6, 19, 43, 66, 80, 66, 43, 19, 6, 1, 1$$

Finally, a small "dirty" picture I made to illustrate the 10 chords and how you can move by stepwise motions between them, i.e. by altering just one tone a half step up or down.

[image: Stepwise motions between chords]

Comment: Wow! thumbs up for the answer.

Comment: My suggestion to adapt this to guitar is to first see what are the positions you can handle on your fretboard up to translations (that is moving up or down on the frets), this will be your space of possible chords. Then, figure out besides translations what chords you consider to be equivalent. For instance inversions of chords. Then combine this like I did into the formula of Burnside's lemma.

Comment: This post is what made me finally understand Burnside's Lemma. +1